# No cite function writing "no cite" at the top of my Rmd document

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown

I am trying to figure out how to get a reference sheet without citing sources in text,
from what I understand I am supposed to use:

```
# References
---
nocite: '@*'
...
```

the thing is when I do this when I knit the document all I get is

[image]

but when I add that section of `nocite` code into the YAML header like this:

[image]

it produces a reference sheet like normal but then at the top of the document i get this:

[image]

Could someone explain how I can create a bibliography without using in-text citations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the advice from Rstudio [here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html#Unused_References_(nocite)), you need to format it like this:

```
---
title: "Stack Overflow Answer"
author: "duckmayr"
date: "1/2/2021"
output: pdf_document
nocite: | 
  @*
bibliography: refs.bib
---
```

(In the `refs.bib` file I have the following contents:)

```
@Article{CameronKastellec2016Are,
  author  = {Charles M. Cameron and Jonathan P. Kastellec},
  title   = {Are {S}upreme {C}ourt nominations a move the median game?},
  journal = {American Political Science Review},
  year    = {2016},
  volume  = {110},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {778--797},
}
```

This results in the following document:

[image]

To make the difference a little more explicit, you have to change

```
nocite: '@*'
```

to

```
nocite: |
  @*
```

### Update: Using `natbib`

If you want to use the `natbib` citation package, then you simply need to use the LaTeX command for generating the citations, like so:

```
---
title: "Stack Overflow Answer"
author: "duckmayr"
date: "1/2/2021"
output:
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: natbib
bibliography: refs.bib
---

\nocite{*}
```

This results in the following document:

[image]

Comment: instead of using a references section in the header how could I use a bibliography because I tried doing nocite: '@*' and when I knit the document no references were created.

Comment: @ashak04 I have updated my answer to show an example of using `@*`

Comment: @ashak04 I also made a small update to highlight more the formatting differences that are causing your issue. Remember to select the checkmark if this solves your issue, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)!

Comment: I tried using your example with @* and for some reason none of references are being printed out, my references.bib file has 3 references but none of them are being printed using your example, could there be something I could change to fix this?

Comment: @ashak04 Hmm... in that case it looks like we need some more information (you may want to look at the page on [mcve]). Can you edit your question to include: Your full YAML header; and your `bib` file? Then I could see if your same YAML header causes an issue on my machine and find out where the problem is. Thanks

Comment: I think my citation package was causing the problem, when I removed it the problem went away, is there a way i could use a citation package and still use this solution?

Comment: @ashak04 What citation package?

Comment: I use natbib and when I was using it the references would not be produced when using your solution, I was hoping that maybe there could be a way for me to use natbib and your solution at the same time

Comment: @ashak04 I updated the answer to show how to do it with `natbib`